# WebBrowser.Document is null on return from thread, not updating in new thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, web-scraping

```
public static User registerUser()
{
    Uri test = new Uri("https://www.example.com/signup");
    HtmlDocument testdoc = runBrowserThread(test);

    string tosend = "test";

    User user = new User();

    user.apikey = tosend;

    return user;

}
public static HtmlDocument runBrowserThread(Uri url)
{
    HtmlDocument value = null;
    var th = new Thread(() =>
    {
        var br = new WebBrowser();
        br.DocumentCompleted += browser_DocumentCompleted;
        br.Navigate(url);
        value = br.Document;
        Application.Run();
    });
    th.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
    th.Start();
    th.Join(8000); 
    return value;
}

static void browser_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    var br = sender as WebBrowser;
    if (br.Url == e.Url)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Natigated to {0}", e.Url);
        Console.WriteLine(br.Document.Body.InnerHtml);
        System.Console.ReadLine();
        Application.ExitThread();   // Stops the thread
    }
}
```

I am trying to scan this page, and while it does get the HTML it does not pass it back in to the function call, but instead sends back null (I presume that is post processing).

How can I make it so that the new thread passes back its result?

Answer (score 1):

There are several problems with your approach.

- You're not waiting till the webpage is navigated, I mean till `Navigated` event. So document could be null till then.
- You're quitting after 8 seconds, if page takes more than 8 seconds to load you won't get the document.
- If document isn't properly loaded, you're leaving the thread alive.
- I guess `WebBrowser` control will not work as expected unless you add it into a form and show it(it needs to be visible in screen).

Etc..

Don't mix up things. Your goal can't be to use `WebBrowser`. If you need to just download the string from webpage, use [HttpClient.GetStringAsync](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh551746%28v=vs.118%29.aspx).

Once you get the page as string format, If you want to manipulate the html, use [HtmlAgilityPack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/846994/how-to-use-html-agility-pack).

Comment: 1) Using webbrowser because I need it to executed JS

2) Okay, I'll use navigated event, thanks

3) its actually working, just not returning the result. It spits the html into the console window

Answer (score 0):

Moved over to using WaitN instead of the default browser model. A bit buggy but now works like it should do.

```
using (var browser = new FireFox("https://www.example.com/signup"))
        {
            browser.GoTo("https://example.com/signup");
            browser.WaitForComplete();


        }
```